# SFTP spring integration - authentication failure

Tags: spring-integration

There is one SFTP server and I have read/write access to a particular folder on this server. I am not allowed/able to access any other location (folder) on this server.
I am able to connect to this server using WinSCP client or putty and can perform read/write to the folder assigned to me successfully.
I am using user/password based authentication.

When i try to connect to same server -location using spring integration i get following exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session 
        at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:354)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:300)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to connect 
        at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:250) 
        at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:349)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: 2 Too many authentication failures for root
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.read(Session.java:987)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.UserAuthPassword.start(UserAuthPassword.java:91)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:463)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
        at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:241)
```

configuration i am using is:

```
<bean id="sftpServerFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
        <property name="host" value="${serverLocation}"/>
        <property name="port" value="${port}"/>
        <property name="user" value = "${username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${userpassword}"/>
    </bean>
```

I request to guide me to solve this issue.

Comment: I solve it by putting server details; host,port,user/psw directly in configuration.

Comment: Great! So, please delete a question or provide an answer to close it properly and help others to solve similar problem in the future

Comment: Deleting Q is not a problem, i can but i don't know how to delete it. Solution i have already mentioned that i had to put server details directly in configuration file. It is reading property values on Windows machine successfully but on Linux (RedHat) it is not reading so i put values in configuration file. I know this is not the proper solution, i am looking into this and hopefully will be able to solve. If you can guide on this then it would be great.